# hasFile is false(Upload files) Laravel 5.8/Angular 7

Tags: laravel, angular7

I'm sending data of Angular 7, all the data I can see in controller Laravel 5.8, only the image not work

My view

```
<img [src]="_image" alt="" class="image-exercise" (click)="selectFile.click()">
<input type="file" (change)="getImage($event)" style="display: none" #selectFile>
```

method to get image ts

```
getImage(ev) {   
 console.log(ev.target.files[0]);
  if(ev.target.files.length > 0) {
   this.selectImage = ev.target.files[0];  
    const reader = new FileReader();    
    reader.onload = () => {
     this._image = <string>reader.result; 
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.selectImage);
   // this.form.get('image').setValue(this.selectImage);
  }  
}
```

and finally my controller

```
if($request->hasFile('image')) { 
    $image = $request->file('image'); 
    $nameImage = uniqid(date('YmdHis')). '.' .$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $upload = $image->move(public_path('images'), $nameImage);   
}
```

I get File in Angular

```
File {name: "empresaria.png", lastModified: 1562158315388, lastModifiedDate: Wed Jul 03 2019 09:51:55 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 69449, …}
lastModified: 1562158315388
lastModifiedDate: Wed Jul 03 2019 09:51:55 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília) {}
name: "empresaria.png"
size: 69449
type: "image/png"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
```

but if I do it

```
return response()->json($request->hasFile('image'));
```

its return false, the other data its ok, only image ........???????

Comment: I think `name="image"` is missing in input element

Comment: I don't take name in input but I have the "name" here in form this.form.value.image = this.selectImage; and the result still get image empty  {name: "teste", label: "as6d5f46s5d4s", image: Array(0), status: 1}

Comment: Note, I put this way this.form.value.image = this.selectImage; and its get the value no problem, but in controller it' empty, I dont understant

Comment: Can you include the JS code that actually sends the image to your controller? Try dump the whole request to see what is atually being sent - `dd($request->all())`.

Comment: so it is a API and the return is in JSON and when put response()->json($request->all()) the return is empty {name: "teste", label: "as6d5f46s5d4s", image: Array(0), status: 1}, look a field here in controllerAPI is empty but there in angular to be ok